# Can seasoning be eaten without being cooked?

Tags: steak, seasoning

I use the steak seasoning for cooking steak (season on steak before being cook)

I love the seasoning so much that, even after fully cooked, I still add a lot to the steak, is it okay? Are there any side effect?

[image]

Comment: The stuff is shelf stable in a grinder. It should be fine without cooking.

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to cook it, it's fine to eat straight out of the grinder. It's just green, black and pink peppercorns with dried garlic, salt and dried onion (ingredient list from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005VH09SA)).